# How to do polar interpolation in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, polar-coordinates

I have a scalar quantity `Q(r, theta)` which I want to interpolate in polar coordinates. The problem is theta runs from 0 to 2π. Thus there is a discontinuity at the 0 and 2π interface, which is creating the problem.

My original data is on an unstructured grid, so I am using griddata in MATLAB.

Comment: It is not clear from the question what is the problem. Could you add some code or elaborate some more. Why would there be a discontinuity ? since 0=2*pi to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I would triangulate the domain, essentially converting to cartesian coordinates. The triangulation will wrap of course, since it no longer cares about the discontinuity. Now interpolation inside the triangulation will be trivial, and it will use the information properly that lies across that periodic boundary. (`TriScatteredInterp` will suffice for this problem, once you convert to Cartesian coordinates.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the data from 0 to 2π. I expand them from -π to 3π, which contains the section of [0, 2π], so the data become successive. Then I use the expanded data to interpolate the grid located in [0, 2π]. There is a hypothesis that the period is 2π.

You must know that the phenomenon of discontinuity is because the interpolation function thinks that 0 and 2π are the **edges** of the data, but actually they are not for polar coordinates.

[image: the code which I used]

```
[newele,newazi,newmp1]=expandData(ele,azi,mp1); 
elegrid = linspace(0,90,20); % Elevation of gridPoints 
azigrid = linspace(0,360,30); % Azimuth of gridPoints 
[X,Y] = meshgrid(elegrid,azigrid); 
Z = griddata(newele,newazi,newmp1,X,Y,'nearest');
```

Comment: [newele,newazi,newmp1]=expandData(ele,azi,mp1);
                        elegrid = linspace(0,90,20); % Elevation of gridPoints
                        azigrid = linspace(0,360,30); % Azimuth of gridPoints
                        [X,Y] = meshgrid(elegrid,azigrid);                        
                        Z = griddata(newele,newazi,newmp1,X,Y,'nearest');